# Make background image repeat even after scrolling to the right

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-repeat

This is the problem
http://screencast.com/t/Dgfd5vTeEY

This is the site
http://eotomarketingsystems.com/

I have looked everywhere but the only method i got the background image to be full width. was by using the method here: [CSS Tricks—Full Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), 
but it was made background-image fixed which messed everything up. is there a simpler way to just make it reach that area after you scroll to the right?

Comment: why there's a scrollbar? I suggest remove it and set max or fixed width to your container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now Define** `min-width` in your **body css** as like this

if your `main wraper` **width** is `980px;`

than define your

```
body{
min-width:980px;
}
```